# Appropiate ordination methods for compositional (percent) microbial species abundances explained by continous environmental variables

Tags: multivariate-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

I aim to investigate the impact of various continuous environmental factors (such as nitrogen, phosphorus, etc.) on the composition of microbial communities within soil samples. These environmental assessments and microbial composition data were obtained concurrently from the same soil specimens. A total of 30 soil specimens were collected, comprising two specimens from each of 15 distinct sites.

The data on microbial community composition is presented as relative abundances of Operational Taxonomic Units (OTUs), with each sample's OTU percentages totaling 100%.

There are many microbial species in the dataset that have abundances of 0 either in many/several samples or for some species in all samples. For this type of species data as i understand the Hellinger transformation could be useful for some ordination methods. However log (x + 1) would be more appropiate on species data in the form of actual counts. Any thoughts on transformations worth considering?

The first DCA axis (gradient length) length is below 3, so as I understand linear methods are recommended (https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/multivariate-analysis-of-ecological-data-using-canoco-5/E889D58A80BCAA333825A490458D1D19). For relative abundance data I see that CA and NMDS can be used (https://fukamilab.github.io/BIO202/06-A-unconstrained-ordination.html), however CA is not a linear method and is for long gradients lengths. Also CA is not a constrained method. So then I'm left with NMDS. Constrained RDA also seems viable, and it may suffice with the Hellinger transform. Does this seem appropiate? If not which methods/ordination methods that would be appropiate for this? Also interesting to know about alternatives also in case NMDS is appropiate. Tips about good and relevant references would also be highly appreciated.